# Statement not firing after a `foreach` within a `using` block

Tags: c#, event-handling, foreach, using

I'm trying to concatenate some data within a `foreach` iterator within a `using` block. Unfortunately, for some reason, any statements I insert into (or after) the `using` block after the `foreach` fail to fire.

Source:

```
static void sensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (var depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {          
        if (depthFrame == null)
            return;
        short[] bits = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
        string bitString = "0";
        depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(bits);
        foreach (var bit in bits)
        {
            bitString += bit.ToString();
            Console.Write("This fires.");
        }
        Console.Write("This never fires and I don't know why.");
        Program.Broadcast(bitString); //this also fails to fire.
    }
    Console.Write("This never fires either.");
}
```

Comment: Try a `Console.WriteLine()` after Program.Broadcast to see if there is cached output that is there but you're not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the foreach takes too long? try using StringBuilder.

```
        StringBuilder bitString = new StringBuilder("0");
        depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(bits);
        foreach (var bit in bits)
        {
            sb.Append(bit.ToString();
        }
        Program.Broadcast(bitString.ToString());
```

Comment: Maybe he just doesn't wait long enough, and the string concat takes too long, so he doesn't see what fires after the foreach...

Comment: Agree that since what the OP is describing is otherwise impossible if the program actually completed, it's possible that it hasn't exited the loop.

Comment: This seems to work! :)

Can you help me understand why using StringBuilder is working and concatenating to a string is not?

Comment: @MonkeyApocalypse, `StringBuilder` is designed to be appended to.  Adding strings to it has a low fixed cost.  When you use `+=`, it must instantiate a brand new (and increasingly large) `string` on each iteration, which becomes progressively more expensive the further you get into the loop.  Presumably if you didn't run out of memory, your original solution would have eventually finished as well.

Comment: Thanks @KirkWoll! Since this is an event handler firing 30x a second, I'm assuming that I just murdered the memory...

Comment: you can in increase efficiency still by setting the capacity of the stringbuilder to the bits array size. This way the string builder wont need to resize or at least not as frequently

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code there's no obvious reason for it not to work. I doubt it has anything to do with the `using()` block.

Maybe check the following:

1. Is your `foreach` loop terminating? How many elements are in the `bits` array and how many times is "This Fires" being written out?
2. The console output may be getting buffered and you aren't seeing anything printed until it is flushed. What happens if you replace `Console.Write()` with `Console.WriteLine()`?
3. The only other way execution could be breaking out of the loop without reaching `Program.Broadcast(bitString)` is if an exception is being thrown. Try wrapping the whole function in a `try`/`catch`/`finally` construct and print any exceptions that occur, and possibly a message in the `finally` block that should be printed no matter what happens.

Hope that helps.

Comment: 1. After some other discussion and looking at it some more, I think this is where the problem lies. Since this is an event handler being called 30 times a second (from a device I cannot throttle), I get an endless stream of "this fires" in the console at a rate of several hundred times a second. 
2. Tried that. No dice. :(
3. Also tried that. Also no dice. 

By process of elimination, I guess that leaves #1.

Thanks for the help :)